# Using zosftplib copied a sas dataset with downoad binary and tried to open in pandas read sas for reading

Tags: python, pandas, sas, mainframe, ftplib

```
import zosftplib
import pandas as pd
import ebcdic
Myzftp = zosftplib.Zftp(mvshost,mvsuser, passwd,
                timeout=500.0, sbdataconn='(ibm-1147,iso8859-1)')

Myzftp.download_binary('DATASET.OF.SAS', '/tmp/sasdata.sas7bdat')

data =pd.read_sas('/tmp/sasdata.sas7bdat',encoding="cp-1141")
```

I am unable to read sas dataset, and pandas is throwing error Stating it's not a sas data

Comment: Are you sure that READ_SAS can work with a datasets generated on an IBM mainframe?

Comment: Not sure on that, if at all, if I want to read that dataset Generated from mainframe what steps do I need to follow ?

Comment: Personally I would run SAS on the mainframe and create a more portable version of the file.  So a SAS transport file perhaps.  Or possibly a CSV file and a separate file with the metadata about the variables.  Then you can download that and read it into Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think the challenge you're running into is that the CP applies to all data fields.  SAS datasets are a combination of textual and binary data; as such, a blanket conversion likely won't help.  @tom's suggestion of converting on platform is the best alternative.

This [article](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi25/25/cc/25p101.pdf) from SAS may help.